# Query to check if two numbers share first n digits (starts with another number)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, startswith

Suppose that I have the following Tables:

```sql
create table #Temp1(number int)
insert into #Temp1 values (12345),(123456),(1234567)

create table #Temp2(number int)
insert into #Temp2 values (123),(123456),(2345)

select * from #Temp1
select * from #Temp2
```

```sql
#Temp1        #Temp2
+---------+   +---------+
|  number |   |  number |
+---------+   +---------+
|  12345  |   |   123   |
|  123456 |   |  123456 |
| 1234567 |   |   2345  |
+---------+   +---------+
```

I want to check if #Temp1.number starts with #Temp2.number. Something like this:

```sql
+-------------+------------+
| this number | found here |
+-------------+------------+
|    123      |    12345   |
|    123      |    123456  |
|    123      |   1234567  |
|   123456    |    123456  |
|   123456    |   1234567  |
+-------------+------------+
```

**Note:** `2345` is not found, because none of numbers in #Temp1 starts with `2345`

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? The 2 are completely different products.

Comment: Hint: Treat your numbers as strings instead, and this turns into simple pattern matching.

Comment: @Larnu SQL-Server it is, thanks

Comment: @Tabaraei you can see what I edited by clicking on the link "edited 8 hours ago". I can't see who downvoted you, but my guess is because you didn't show any research or any attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just need to convert to a `varchar` and then use a `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT T1.number,
       T2.number
FROM #Temp1 T1
     JOIN #Temp2 T2 ON CONVERT(varchar(20),T1.number) LIKE CONVERT(varchar(20),T2.number) + '%';
```

Note that, due to the conversion, this will not be performant for large data sets as the query is not SARGable.

Comment: It also returns that `123456` is found in `12345`, which is not correct. I just want it to check if the numbers in the second table are found within the first one.

Comment: But that's what you want in your expected results @Tabaraei ... If you *don't* want that remove the second clause in the `JOIN`, but it will *not* be reflective of your expected results.

Comment: I'm really sorry! You're right, gonna fix this.

Comment: Is there any way to change this that it doesn't return the same numbers? so `12345` is not found in `12345`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually we can avoid converting the two numbers to strings, and instead do a direct numerical comparison using `LOG10` and `POWER`:

```sql
SELECT t1.number, t2.number
FROM Temp1 t1
INNER JOIN Temp2 t2
    ON t1.number >= t2.number
WHERE
    t1.number / POWER(10, FLOOR(LOG10(t1.number)) - FLOOR(LOG10(t2.number))) - t2.number = 0;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

The logic here e.g. for checking if `12345` begins with `123` is first to figure out how many tens places the former is larger than the latter.  In this case, it is by a factor of 100.  So, we divide `12345` by 100 to get `123`, then we find that it matches with the prefix from the second table.